# insert javascript date and time objects to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i have date and time display on my form, Now my problem is on how 
 can i insert the value of date and time to database, hope you can help me. Thanks.

here is my code for date and time:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:300px;">
             <label>Date:</label>  
             <span id="date" name="calendar"></span>
             </div>
              <div class="row" style="margin-left:300px;">
             <label>Time:</label> 
            <span id="clock" name="time"></span>
             </div>
```

my php code:

```
<?php
include_once ('connection.php');
$calendar=$_POST["calendar"];
$calendar=date("Y-m-d",$calendar);
$time=$_POST["time"];
$time=date("h-i-s",$time);


        $InsertSql = "INSERT INTO test2(date,timein) VALUES ('$calendar','$time')";
          $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql);

?>
```

javascript for the date and time:

```
<script>
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var n = new Date();
var y = n.getFullYear();
var m = n.getMonth();
var d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = months[m] + " " + d + " " + y;
</script>

<script>
(function () {

  var clockElement = document.getElementById( "clock" );

  function updateClock ( clock ) {
    clock.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  }

  setInterval(function () {
      updateClock( clockElement );
  }, 1000);

}());
</script>
```

Updated My Question.

[here is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4JMv.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af0BP.png)

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: on how can i insert the value of the date and time display on my form to database

Comment: How do you insert any other value from a form into your database?

Comment: But one thing... never ever just put variables into an SQL query - that is the quickest way to bring attacked by SQL injection. Use prepared statements

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. Also tell us what you have tried. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What you need is Ajax.

Comment: thank you, i'll just update my tags. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about store it in a variable. something like this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button name="submit" class="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$calendar=date("Y-m-d");
$time=date("H:i:s");
$InsertSql = "INSERT INTO test2(date,timein) VALUES ('$calendar','$time')";
          $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql);
}        

?>
```